# Return all rows if joined table contains no rows, otherwise return only matched rows

Tags: sql-server

Database structure

```
CREATE TABLE SalesOrder
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Reference NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SalesOrder_CustomerID ON SalesOrder (CustomerID);

CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
```

Example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b69d/1)

Table-valued variable `@SelectedCustomers` can be empty or containing list of customer's `ID` selected by user.
This query return orders of the selected customers and returns nothing if selected list is empty

```
SELECT so.ID
, so.Reference
, c.Name AS CustomerName
FROM SalesOrder so
INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.ID = so.CustomerID
WHERE so.CustomerID IN (SELECT ID FROM @SelectedCustomers)
```

But I need to return all rows if variable is empty
I tried `OR` keyword, but this approach isn't index friendly and query become very slow.

Currently I generate query in the application's code(`.NET`).
If list contains some values, then
`WHERE so.CustomerID IN (SELECT ID FROM @SelectedCustomers)` clause added to the query

Question: Does exists some other way to get needed result in more efficient way?

Comment: One way would be using an if-else. Check if count(*) from @SelectedCustomers > 0 then use query with where clause, else use query without where clause. You might need to benchmark it yourself

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a single sql query? Couldn't you check the variable in the calling code and execute one sql statement if the variable is empty and a second different query if the variable is not?

Comment: This is exactly what I doing right now (I mentioned this in the question) - generating needed query in the application(calling) code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the same
As this would return if @SelectedCustomers had value(s) but not matching

```
SELECT so.ID
     , so.Reference
     , c.Name AS CustomerName
FROM SalesOrder so
INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.ID = so.CustomerID 
LEFT  JOIN @SelectedCustomers s on so.CustomerID = s.ID 
WHERE s.ID is null
```

a union might work

```
SELECT so.ID
     , so.Reference
     , c.Name AS CustomerName
 FROM SalesOrder so
JOIN Customer c ON c.ID = so.CustomerID 
JOIN @SelectedCustomers on so.CustomerID = @SelectedCustomers.ID 
union 
SELECT so.ID
     , so.Reference
     , c.Name AS CustomerName
FROM SalesOrder so
JOIN Customer c ON c.ID = so.CustomerID 
where (select top 1 ID from @SelectedCustomers) is null
```

Or I know it sounds crazy but if no rows in @SelectedCustomers then insert all distinct ID.  You get out of the OR.

Comment: First query will not work, because always return all orders(rows). Second query with `UNION` seems working. But I used `WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @SelectedCustomers)` instead of `SELECT TOP 1`. And I removed some syntax errors from second query

Comment: :) This line `JOIN @SelectedCustomers on so.CustomerID = @SelectedCustomers.ID` will generate error _Must declare the scalar variable "@SelectedCustomers"._ After adding alias name working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the where end of the where statement:

Or @selectedcustomer is null

Comment: OP already tried "OR..." and is looking for something more performant.

Comment: `@SelectedCustomers IS NULL` condition will not work because `@SelectedCustomers` is table-valued type

Comment: Or (select count * from @SelectedCustomers)=0

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I do not want using `OR` because of slow performance

Comment: Please post if you find a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but this might work:

```
SELECT so.ID
    , so.Reference
    , c.Name AS CustomerName
FROM SalesOrder so
INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.ID = so.CustomerID
INNER JOIN @SelectedCustomers s on c.ID = COALESCE(s.ID, c.ID)
```

Comment: This query returns no rows if `@SelectedCustomers` is empty